# Jquery modify html with each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a problem with jQuery. I want to write a function that dynamically replaces some content in my HTML.

This is the function:

```
function renderPage(datas, html) {
    $(html).find("*").each(function(){
       if ($(this).attr("data-func")) {
           var df = $(this).attr("data-func");
           var content = null;
           eval("content = " + df + "($(this),datas);");
           console.log(content);
       }
    });
}
```

The problem is, that it has no effect! I see in the log that the content variable is right, but the output is not different.

My function in eval:

```
function fill(element,data) {
    element.html("BASSZA MEG");
    var events = data.events;

    var i = 0;
    var n = events.length;

    for (;i<n; i++) {
        obj = events[i];
        var tr = $("<tr>");
        var nev = $("<td>");
        var link = $("<a href='programbelso.html#id="+obj["event_id"]+"&logo="+obj["event_logo"]+"'>");
        link.html(obj["event_name"]);
        nev.append(link);
        tr.append(nev);
        element.append(tr);
    }

    console.log("element: " + element);
    return element;
}
```

Comment: And what did the console say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do NOT loop over every single element in the document, and then use an `if()` statement. You can drastically improve the performance by using the right selector.

The following sample should achieve what you're trying to do without needing to use the evil `eval()` function, too:

```
function renderPage(datas, html) {
    $('[data-func]').each(function() {
       var df = $(this).attr("data-func");
       var the_func = window[$(this).attr("data-func")]; 

       if(typeof the_func === 'function') {
           var content = the_func($(this), datas);
           console.log(content);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: What actually appears in the console?